# oracle jdbcTemplate Invalid column type

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I am using below code while deleting a row from database

```
jdbcTemplateObject.update("DELETE FROM SUPERVISION_ROOM cl WHERE cl.fk_group IN ? and cl.fk_room IN ?", gourpIds, deleteExamDTO.getRoomIds());
```

But i getting following exception:

> PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [DELETE
> FROM SUPERVISION_ROOM cl WHERE cl.fk_group IN ? and cl.fk_room IN ?];
> SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested
> exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type] with root
> cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBCTemplate does not support a *transparent* IN list binding as you try to use it.

It is documented in [11.7.3. Passing in lists of values for IN clause](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html)

> You would have to either have a number of variations with the desired number of place holders prepared or you would have to dynamically generate the SQL string once you know how many place holders are required.

So basically you must first *expand* the SQL statement with the right number of *placeholders* and then pass each element as a separate paramater.

```
...
WHERE cl.fk_group IN (?,?,?,?) and cl.fk_room IN (?,?)
```