# jdbcTemplate: Invalid column type in delete query

Tags: spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I used jdbcTemplate in my projet spring boot, i tried to delete a row with the below script, it work fine

```
String ids1 = String.join(",", gourpIds.stream().map(id -> id+"").collect(Collectors.toList()));
String ids2 = String.join(",", deleteExamDTO.getRoomIds().stream().map(id -> id+"").collect(Collectors.toList()));

jdbcTemplateObject.update(String.format("DELETE FROM SUPERVISION_ROOM cl WHERE cl.FK_GROUP IN (%s)", ids1), gourpIds.toArray());
```

but when i add another param in my query like below i get this error `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type`

```
jdbcTemplateObject.update(String.format("DELETE FROM SUPERVISION_ROOM cl WHERE cl.FK_GROUP IN (%s) AND cl.FK_ROOM IN (%s)", ids1, ids2), gourpIds.toArray(), deleteExamDTO.getRoomIds().toArray());
```

Comment: You're calling `update` with an array of something for the parameters, while the query you uses doesn't have any parameters. Also, please provide the full exception stacktrace, a [mre], and explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66678011/4808122). In general a textual substitution of the parameters in the SQL query is not recommended for the  performance and security reasons. To troubleshoot it simple print the SQL string before the exceution and check it - you'll get the same error if you executes it e.g. in SQL Developer.